# Nullish coalescing operator not working or not enabled?

Tags: javascript

I was looking into how to set a variable in javascript and I found out about the **Nullish coalescing operator (??)** in one of the posts I saw on here.

But now, when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
Unexpected token, expected ,
```

for this line:

```
var oldBookScript = (localStorage.getItem(book.id) ?? newBookScript);
```

I want the variable `oldBookScript` to have the value of `localStorage.getItem(book.id)` but if that is null or empty, I want it to have the value of `newBookScript`

Do I need to enable it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: is this a vanilla js project or are you using a js framework like react, vue, etc.

Comment: It's inside of a React component...since you asked, I am guessing I can't do that in React?  thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you checked the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility)?

Comment: That feature requires an up-to-date JavaScript runtime. How did you test your code? In a browser? In Node.js?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell it has nothing to do with React, it's a JavaScript version thing.

Comment: @Barmar I am using this in Version 91.0.4472.124 of Chrome

Comment: @Pointy I am testing in Chrome Version 91.0.4472.124

Comment: are you sure the error is in this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a syntactical construct, which means that in order to run code with it, you need to be in an environment that's up-to-date enough to support it.

For example, the most recent versions of Node, Chrome, and Firefox (among others) will all run fine with your code, but older environments (like IE11) will throw a SyntaxError.

In standard scripts, given that it's syntax, there's no way to "enable" it on a particular environment - either it's supported or it isn't. The usual approach in this situation is to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the source code (which has all the modern syntax) down to ES6 or ES5 so that obsolete browsers can understand it.

But if you're using React, your code's JSX is already being transpiled. The most up-to-date versions of create-react-app [does support the nullish coalescing operator](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.3.0). Upgrade to a more recent version of create-react-app, if possible. If you have a more manual setup, you'll need to make sure your code is being transpiled with Babel and use Babel [7.8.0 or later](https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/01/11/7.8.0).

See [these docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/#jsx-and-react) from Babel on integrating it into React via the `@babel/preset-react` preset.