# How to reuse the following piece of code?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-functions

I am learning React and encountered a following situation:
I have several components with behaviour depending on the size of the container. Naturally, I want everything to be responsive, so i need to get the size dynamically. I do it this way:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const ComponentOne = () => {
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  const handleSize = () => {
    setDimensions({
      width: refContainer.current.offsetWidth,
      height: refContainer.current.offsetHeight,
    });
  };

  /* Run first time */
  useEffect(() => {
    handleSize();
  }, []);

  /* Run on resize */
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleSize);
  }, []);

  /* Some useful code which depends on those dimensions here
    .....
    */

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={refContainer}>Something produced by that useful code</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentOne;
```

Everything works fine.
Now, imagine I need 5 components like this. I there a way to have some helper function/module, with container name as parameter, returning the dimensions of that container?

p.s. As far as re-using code goes, HOCs work just fine. I couldn't apply it to my case though, was unable to use the `ref` attribute from my Component in the HOC, nor to pass it down from HOC to Component.
In the meantime i've found a nice one-liner in an external library `react-cool-dimensions`:

```
const { observe, width, height } = useDimensions();
```

and set `ref={observe}`.
No hooks needed in the Component itself, load and resizing events are caught inside the `useDimensions` function.

Comment: Why are you using two `useEffect`s?

Comment: You can create a custom hook that accepts a ref and returns dimension that you can use later. Since use of dimension is not shown, cannot comment on what to do next

Comment: In addition to @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ comment, you should also return a cleanup function after adding an event listener.

Comment: think you should reference several Q&As on how others are using width and heights with event listeners.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ My "useful code" generates several random points inside the container. If I remove first useEffect - on the first load width and height = 0, as i initiate them in useState. If i just try to call `handleSize()` instead of useEffect - i get error as `refContainer.current` is undefined yet. How do i make one useEffect for both initial load and window resize?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js: useEffect with window resize event listener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846043/react-js-useeffect-with-window-resize-event-listener-not-working)

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Yes thank you! Din't realise I can put two listeners inside. Ok, now I  have one useEffect, and also looked up and added cleanUp return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use case for a [Higher Order Component](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

I've not tested this, so you might need to tweak it to get it working; but the following code creates a higher order component that wraps your component. So long as your component has a `width` and a `height` prop, it should auto-populate them.

```
export const withDimensions = (
  component,
  componentName = component.displayName ?? component.name
) => {
  const WithDimensions = (props) => {
    const refContainer = useRef();
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    });

    const handleSize = () => {
      setDimensions({
        width: refContainer.current?.offsetWidth ?? 0,
        height: refContainer.current?.offsetHeight ?? 0,
      });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      handleSize();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleSize);
    }, []);

    return component({ ...props, ...dimensions, ref: refContainer });
  };

  WithDimensions.displayName = `withSampleHoC(${componentName})`;

  return WithDimensions;
};
```

Comment: Why would you introduce TypeScript to someone who mentions they're new to React and already having an issue understanding `useEffect`?

Comment: Good point. I can strip the types.

Comment: @BenWainwright Ok, i see it is not TS specific. Looks very much like a Python decorator. Will try now, thank you!

Comment: I've edited to remove the types :)

Comment: @AlexBachurin I've just realised I forgot to pass the ref into the wrapped component. Updated :)

Comment: @BenWainwright struggling to put the code in a comment .. In short, it fails to compile. Should I use some specific compiler?

Comment: @BenWainwright Aha .. specifically, for some reason it does not like the "??" in:
    const componentName = component.displayName ?? component.name;
strange .. but ok, will keep looking )

Comment: @BenWainwright if you are curious found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413983/nullish-coalescing-operator-not-working-or-not-enabled
Ok, sorry, already took enough of your time. Thank you! )

Comment: oh, that can be replaced with this `component.displayName || component.name`

Comment: @BenWainwright yeah .. but then there is a nice object.field?.subfield syntax, which is not recognised as well. Googling shows people regularly encounter problems with "Nullish coalescing" with create-react-app, up to this day.
Of course, i can rewrite without "?." and "??" but this is irritating )

Comment: @BenWainwright I was fighting with HOCs for half a day, learned a lot of useful new stuff. They work great as decorators if i need to modify some props or add some behaviour (like logging). But was unable to make it work in my case - `ref` always stays undefined in the base component, hence unable to extract dimensions. Tried `forwardRef` and a lot of other stuff down the rabbit hole - to no avail.
I will accept your answer as it is a correct answer for a wider question of "how to reuse a piece of code".

Comment: Hey @AlexBachurin this approach *does* work, but I didn't explain it properly. I've just tested it - here is a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-sound-w0dhkf?file=/src/App.js
The missing piece of the puzzle is that the components you pass into the HOC need to take a ref as a prop, and they need to pass it into the element you are trying to measure. I'll update my answer in a bit to reflect this extra info

Comment: Yes! It works, thank you. A shame I didn't see it myself immediately, as dictionary union syntax - `{...dict_1, ...dict_2}` is actually almost the same as in Python, and works same way. And React function props are the same as `**qwargs` in Python. p.s. I am basically rewriting a Python Dash app frontend in React JS, learning it as I go.

Comment: Just an observation though as I think about this a bit more; its not great practise to make your app responsive to window/device size using JavaScript. These days, almost everything you need to be done can be done with CSS. If you do it using JS, you'll likely risk making an app that is horrible to use for non visual users (ie - people using screen readers) - because you'll be changing the structure of the app based on something that isn't relevant to them

Comment: @BenWainwright I am only using JS to get 300 random points inside the container. I can do it with, say, SASS, but not sure it makes any difference under the hood. Which are then animated with pure CSS, only if `@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference)`. Not sure how that will "look" on screen-reader though .. Probably my Component should just return `<div></div>`  depending on certain `window.matchMedia` query.

Comment: @BenWainwright I've jut realised i don't need container size at all! I can just set coordinates with %. But i still need to redraw, otherwise the animation goes askew if a user, say, resized the browser window to the left. That is, when animation  is switched on.